# Month dropdown not working properly in datepicker in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to automate the accounts creation page of Salesforce in selenium webdriver java through a demo account. I am reading the data from the excel file in D drive.

In the datepicker field, the year dropdown works fine but the month dropdown select is not working correctly. The month dropdown opens, and the desired month is also highlighted and it also reaches and highlights the desired date tag in the page but then it jumps back to current month i.e. November and selects the date from there.

I am not able to understand this behavior.

```
String date, mon, year;
    int month, day;
    date = sh.getCell(27, 3).getContents();
    year = date.substring(6, 10);
    month = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
    day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
    month = month-1;
    switch(month)
    {
        case 0 : mon = "January";   break;
        case 1 : mon = "February";  break;
        case 2 : mon = "March";     break;
        case 3 : mon = "April";     break;
        case 4 : mon = "May";       break;
        case 5 : mon = "June";      break;
        case 6 : mon = "July";      break;
        case 7 : mon = "August";    break;
        case 8 : mon = "September";     break;
        case 9 : mon = "October";       break;
        case 10 : mon = "November";     break;
        case 11 : mon = "December"; break;
        default : mon="Incorrect month input";
    }
    System.out.println(mon);

    Select dty;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N9000000Ctc7X']")).click();
    dty = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calYearPicker']")));
    dty.selectByVisibleText(year);

    Select dtm;
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calMonthPicker']")).click();
    dtm = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calMonthPicker']")));
    dtm.selectByVisibleText(mon);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement dp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datePicker']/div[2]"));
    List<WebElement> colmn;
    colmn = dp.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    int dat=0; flag=0;

    for(WebElement we : colmn)
    {
        System.out.println(we.getText());
        dat = Integer.parseInt(we.getText());
        String clas = we.getAttribute("class");
        try 
        {                   
            if((day==dat) && ((clas.equals("weekday") || (clas.equals("weekend")))))
            {
                we.click(); Thread.sleep(5000);
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }   
    if(flag==0)
        System.out.println("Incorrect Date");
```

Comment: Can you please provide the site where you are testing your code againtst, in case that's public ? Or else, please provide the html code snippet of the Datepicker above.

Comment: I am testing the Salesforce website i.e. www.salesforce.com and anyone can sign up and create their account and test the application. U can create the account at https://developer.salesforce.com/ and then login to go to the account creation page. There is a date field called SLA expiration date. This datepicker opens up overthere.

Comment: This problem has been resolved. Hence I am closing this question here.

Comment: I was clicking on the month dropdown using click() function. Select functions don't work after clicking specially in Mozilla Firefox. Hence I am closing this question here.

Comment: True. You would've to create object of **Select class**, like this `Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element")));` and then use **'selectByValue or selectByVisibleText or selectByIndex'** method(s) to select the proper dropdown value. On the other hand, **sometimes the dropdown is not made by using "select" tag**, therein you would've to **click on the dropdown first, and then click on the resultant option in the dropdown.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given Below is the comment given by Subh which answers my question correctly.

True. You would've to create object of Select class, like this `Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element")));` and then use 'selectByValue or selectByVisibleText or selectByIndex' method(s) to select the proper dropdown value. On the other hand, sometimes the dropdown is not made by using "select" tag, therein you would've to click on the dropdown first, and then click on the resultant option in the dropdown.